# $_GET method is not set even after passing a query string

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my JQuery code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){
        $('#myButton').click(function(){
            var queryString = $('frmEmployee').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'anotherPhp.php',
                type: 'GET',
                data: queryString,
                success: function(){
                    alert('Success!');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

After clicking myButton, I expect the php code will execute.

```
<?php
    require_once('db_connect.php');
    if(isset($_GET['F_Name'])){
        $F_Name = $_GET['F_Name'];
        $M_Name = $_GET['M_Name'];
        $L_Name = $_GET['L_Name'];

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_employee (F_Name, M_Name, L_Name) VALUES('$F_Name','$M_Name','$L_Name')");
    }
?>
```

My problem is that all of my $_GET functions seems to be empty. But I can see from the address bar all of the data I have passed (using serialize() method). Why?

Comment: Check `print_r($_GET);` in your php code. And could you please insert your URL with QueryString here.

Comment: Do you mean this: http://localhost/serialize%20saving/test.html?F_Name=kj&M_Name=k&L_Name=k&submit=save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you Serialize `$('frmEmployee')`. Its need to be `$('.frmEmployee')` when its a class and `$('#frmEmployee')` when its an ID.

Propably you sending an empty query string now.

Comment: Thats it! But can you explain why these data are  still being displayed in my address bar. Like  this: F_Name=kj&M_Name=k&L_Name=k&submit=save

Comment: Your form method is `method='get'`. So the code also commit your form.

Comment: @Arman Maybe your form is being submitted by clicking on the `#myButton` button. Pass an argument in your event handler function (somethings like `e`) and write `e.preventDefault();` in the first line of it. `$('#myButton').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ... }`.

Comment: @Arman The form is probably still being submitted. If the form has method="GET", the data is encoded in the action/URL.

Comment: So that's why. That is the reason I never thought my JQuery syntax  is wrong, and insisted that the problem is something about the ajax function definition. Thanks.

Comment: But no, my form has no `method` attribute at all. I think Mojtaba's suggestion is true.

Comment: @S.Visser Wow, first time to hear that. Thanks.